# How to do EOF in CLion IDE?

Tags: c, ide, clion, eof

I'm trying to do a simple scan line code in CLion:

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
        char_count++;
    }
```

. I learned in class to type Ctrl-D to do a manual EOF, but this doesn't work in CLion. I've looked at previous questions about the same topic, and the command is enabled in the preferences. Any solutions?

Comment: What SO do you have?

Comment: Aside: be sure to use `int c;`.

Comment: " but this doesn't work in CLion." is vague.  How did it not work?  What code showed the output?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually [a long-known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-5704) about this. Have you tried disabling the option run.processes.with.pty in Registry (Find Action > Registry)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in clion, you can run your code in the terminal.

Like this:

- **first:** `gcc xxx.c` (it will create a file named a.out)
- **second:** `./a.out` (code will run)
- **third:** the terminal will receive your EOF signal

**My point of view:**

It is just a problem in IDE...the code is fine, thinks